# How to declare a concept for binary operations properly

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm implementing the generic fast power algorithm from the `elements of programming` book.

This is a very naive version

```
template <typename R, typename I, typename Op>
requires std::integral<R> && std::integral<I> && std::is_binary_op<Op, R, I, I>
R power(I acc, I a, I n, Op op) {
  while (n-- != I{0}) {
    acc = op(acc, a);
  }
  return acc;
}
```

I'm also trying to enforce requirements on the types passed to the function. But i'm stuck when trying to declare a concept regarding binary operations. this is the two approaches i came up with.

```
// first approach
namespace std {
template <typename Op, typename Ret, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
concept is_binary_op = std::is_same<Op, Ret(Arg1, Arg2)>::value;
}

// second approach
namespace std {
template <typename Op, typename Ret, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
concept is_binary_op = std::is_same < typename std::function<Op>,
typename std::function<Ret(Arg1, Arg2)> >::value;
}
```

Unfortunately, both approaches return false and i cannot find a solution to this problem.

1. Any idea how to fix this ?
2. Why there are no concepts in the standard library checking if a function is unary or binary, etc...

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
After compiling all the feedback that i received (Thanks to everyone). Here is a better version of the original implementation.

```
namespace std {
template <typename Op, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
concept binary_op = std::is_invocable<Op, Arg1, Arg2>::value;
}  // namespace std

template <std::integral I, std::binary_op<I, I> Op>
auto power(I acc, I a, I n, Op op) {
  while (n-- != I{0}) {
    acc = op(acc, a);
  }
  return acc;
}
```

Comment: I would not put a template argument for the return type and instead make it `auto` as it allows for [integer promotion](https://www.demo2s.com/cpp/cpp-integral-promotion.html). Furthermore the way you have written all it does is do a `static_cast` after the calculation.

Comment: BTW, not sure of your "correctness" of the arguments: `acc` and `a` might be of type `R` (which is not necessary `std::integral`)

Comment: Why are you putting all the concepts you've written yourself into the `std` namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea how to fix this ?
> Why there are no concepts in the standard library checking if a function is unary or binary, etc...

[There is a trait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable), for particular argument types. You shouldn't add a concept to `namespace std`.

```
template <typename Op, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
concept binary_op = std::is_invocable_v<Op, Arg1, Arg2>;

template <typename Op, typename Ret, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
concept binary_op_r = std::is_invocable_r_v<Ret, Op, Arg1, Arg2>;
```

N.b. you can express `power` more concisely

```
template <std::integral R, std::integral I, binary_op_r<R, I, I> Op>
requires std::is_assignable_v<I, R>
R power(I acc, I a, I n, Op op) {
  while (n-- != I{0}) {
    acc = op(acc, a);
  }
  return acc;
}
```